# Databricks external hive metastore using Azure SQL DB MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )

Tags: java, hive, azure-sql-database, databricks, hive-metastore

I am trying to setup an external hive metatastore for Databricks, using the following init script:

```
dbutils.fs.put(
"/databricks/scripts/external-metastore.sh",
"""#!/bin/sh
  |# Loads environment variables to determine the correct JDBC driver to use.
  |source /etc/environment
  |# Quoting the label (i.e. EOF) with single quotes to disable variable interpolation.
  |cat << 'EOF' > /databricks/driver/conf/00-custom-spark.conf
  |[driver] {
  |    # Hive specific configuration options.
  |    # spark.hadoop prefix is added to make sure these Hive specific options will propagate to the metastore client.
  |    # JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore
  |    "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" = "jdbc:sqlserver://tst.database.windows.net:1433;database=db;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net"
  |
  |    # Username to use against metastore database
  |    "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" = "admin"
  |
  |    # Password to use against metastore database
  |    "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" = "password"
  |
  |    # Driver class name for a JDBC metastore
  |    "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  |
  |    # Spark specific configuration options
  |    "spark.sql.hive.metastore.version" = "2.3.7"
  |    # Skip this one if <hive-version> is 0.13.x.
  |    "spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars" = "builtin"
  |}
  |EOF
  |""".stripMargin,
overwrite = true)
```

I run this Scala code

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.hive.metastore.version")
```

which outputs:

```
res0: String = 2.3.7
```

However when I try to run:

```
spark.table("diamonds").withColumnRenamed("table", "table_number")
 .write
 .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "diamonds", connectionProperties)
```

I get this error:

```
AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
Caused by: HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Caused by: RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Caused by: InvocationTargetException: 
Caused by: MetaException: Version information not found in metastore.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from the document [External Apache Hive metastore](https://docs.databricks.com/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore.html):

- SQL Server does not work as the underlying metastore database for
  Hive 2.0 and above.

Please try to change the version. And here another same question that you can ref:
[Azure Databricks external Hive Metastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66107803/azure-databricks-external-hive-metastore)

HTH.

Comment: SQL Server does not work as the underlying metastore database for Hive 2.0 and above; however, Azure SQL Database does work and is used

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore